# Magsafe adapter not "fitting" in to MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, magsafe

I have a Mid-2009 MacBook Pro, and all was well before the weekend. Now when I try to fit in the MagSafe charger to the macbook, I am unable to fit it in correctly (but as you can see, it is charging):
[image: Does not fit in]

When I tried to see what was in the macbook side of the adapter, I see some small balls:

[image: Small Balls]

These are not stationary but are sticking to the magnet there. Tiny little balls like this:[image: Tiny li'l balls]

The plug looks like this:
[image: The Plug]

Now, I am worried whether the magsafe power adapter has somehow started "disintegrating" (touch wood) or are these some kind of debris I collected somewhere. All was fine on friday and I travelled with my macbook pro over the weekend. I did not use the charger, neither did I travel to some industrial area to collect metallic debris.

Long story short: should I remove these balls and forget all these, or is it something bigger to worry...

Comment: Could you improve this question by including a photo of the plug?

Comment: @Kevin Done....

Comment: Nice pictures. They help the question a lot!

Comment: Do you have children? Or mischievous co-workers?

Comment: @Dan, first thought this was spam. But too high rep to be a bot :-) (no offence intended). After a second I realize the possible significance. No Dan, no children... (after your edit: no. this is my home comp.)

Comment: @Nivas - The mystery deepens. BTW, this IS spam. I will split with you a million dollars from the bank I own in Nigeria, if you will just send me three tiny round magnets that I need to unlock the magnetic vault locks. ;-)

Comment: @Dan Ray lol...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check your power adapter's plug as to whether the debris stems from there. If the plug is all right, I'd just remove the debris and not worry any more about it.

Comment: I dont thin so, because the leads there are "yellow" - brass or something, and these balls are white. I have removed them for now, hoping nothing happens :)

Comment: The pins in my plug are brass colored as well, so I assume you're safe now. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a macbook air bought in 2017. As I put it into my laptop bag with power pin at the bottom, it picked up a used stapler pin lying there. Power pin just would not sit properly. I removed it and it is working good now! Advice and lesson learnt - put the laptop with power pin facing upwards!